# What is wrong with the following T-SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I need to write a query against an EMP table that returns the EMPNO, ENAME and JOB values for Employees with the jobs SALESMAN and MANAGER using a Subquery in the WHERE clause.

I have this, but am getting the error "too many values".  I'm not sure where the extra values are.  Any help I can get with this, would be appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM SCOTT.emp
WHERE SCOTT.emp.job=(SELECT SCOTT.emp.empno, SCOTT.emp.ename, SCOTT.emp.job
                     FROM SCOTT.emp 
                     WHERE SCOTT.emp.job="SALESMAN" OR SCOTT.emp.job="MANAGER");
```

Comment: should use IN instead of equals.. equals will only expect one value from subquery.  two options 1) IN 2) EXISTS

Comment: Where should I be using it instead of the equals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM SCOTT.emp
WHERE SCOTT.emp.job in(SELECT  SCOTT.emp.job
                 FROM SCOTT.emp 
                 WHERE SCOTT.emp.job="SALESMAN" OR SCOTT.emp.job="MANAGER");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `=` with a subquery.  The subquery can return only one column -- SQL Server doesn't support tuples for such comparisons.

Doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT e.*
FROM SCOTT.emp e
WHERE e.job IN ('SALESMAN', 'MANAGER');
```

There is no need for a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.  It is simply not necessary.

Comment: I understand that.  However, I'm trying to learn about sub queries.  Therefore, I need the subquery.

Comment: @JustinRoohparvar . . . Learn about subqueries in contexts where they are needed or appropriate.  Knowing when not to use subqueries is as important as knowing when to use them.

Comment: Instead of using a subquery in the where clause have it the select clause. That would be approriate. Most of the time in the where clause we use IN or EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for it:

1.you can replace '=' with 'IN' as '='(equal to) only expect one value but in your case there are more than one value.

so your query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM SCOTT.emp
WHERE SCOTT.emp.job IN (SELECT SCOTT.emp.empno, SCOTT.emp.ename, SCOTT.emp.job
                     FROM SCOTT.emp 
                     WHERE SCOTT.emp.job="SALESMAN" OR SCOTT.emp.job="MANAGER");
```

or as mentioned in someone's answer no need to use sub query in your case directly put

```
SELECT *
FROM SCOTT.emp 
WHERE SCOTT.emp.job in ("SALESMAN","MANAGER");
```

2. If you want to use '=' then use it with OR.

   SELECT *
       FROM SCOTT.emp 
       WHERE SCOTT.emp.job ="SALESMAN" OR SCOTT.emp.job ="MANAGER";